# PHP image text write header

Tags: php, image

I want to write on this picture some text

[image]

but i cant because every time i add header happend this

[image]

but i read that i must add header because if i dont add header happend errors, sorry for bad English..

```
<?php
  //Set the Content Type
  header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

  // Create Image From Existing File
  $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('sunset.jpg');

  // Allocate A Color For The Text
  $white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 255, 255);

  // Set Path to Font File
  $font_path = 'font.TTF';

  // Set Text to Be Printed On Image
  $text = "This is a sunset!";

  // Print Text On Image
  imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 300, $white, $font_path, $text);

  // Send Image to Browser
  imagejpeg($jpg_image);

  // Clear Memory
  imagedestroy($jpg_image);
?>
```

Comment: you it works (display the image) when you DONT send the `header`?

Comment: You may find it useful to check the return values of the various image/gd functions to see which one fails.

Comment: if i dont write header it will be error if i write header again will be error.